# how to split sentence with word in python Name Anil Sanadhya Name Interactive Brokers LLC

Tags: python

Name Anil Sanadhya Name Interactive Brokers LLC

this is sentence

how can i split like

Name: [Anil sanadhya, Interactive Brokers LLC]

Comment: Is the format for this string always like this:
"FirstName LastName CompanyName"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first we have to split the string using the `Name` separator.

```
name_string = 'Name Anil Sanadhya Name Interactive Brokers LLC'
names = []
for name in name_string.split('Name'):
    if len(name.strip()) != 0: #checking if the entry is None or empty
        names.append(name.strip()) # Adding it but removing all the white spaces
```

In the `names` variable you will get `['Anil Sanadhya', 'Interactive Brokers LLC']`

Using this if have more than two names i.e., `Name Anil Sanadhya Name Interactive Brokers LLC Name USA Name Huston` It will convert all to an array

Comment: above answer working fine. is same way for "1 Interest income 1,374.64 1a Total ordinary dividends 258.60" splitting this to

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `re.findall` approach here:

```py
inp = "Name Anil Sanadhya Name Interactive Brokers LLC"
output = re.findall(r'\bName (.*?)(?=\bName|$)', inp)
print(output)  # ['Anil Sanadhya ', 'Interactive Brokers LLC']
```